# What's wrong with consuming ConfiguredTaskAwaitable from PortableClassLibrary's class under Debugger from MSTest Runner or Console App?

Tags: c#, console-application, mstest, async-await, portable-class-library

*Note: This is only a Debug-time error, but a very weird one.*

### Problem:

While running with Debugger attached and calling a method, exposed in separate Portable library, returning `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`, we get `InvalidProgramException`.

### Reproduce It:

Having 2 projects:

1. PortableClassLibrary (supporting .Net 4.5; Windows Store; Windows Phone 8) 
   with 1 class:

   ```
   public class Weird
   {
       public static ConfiguredTaskAwaitable GetConfiguredTaskAwaitable()
       {
           return new ConfiguredTaskAwaitable();
       }
   }
   ```
2. ConsoleApplication with code:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Weird.GetConfiguredTaskAwaitable();
   }
   ```

### Notes:

1. replacing `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` with `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T>` (a generic version) fixes this strange issue
2. consuming this method form WP8 or Win8 app under Debugger works fine.

Currently it causes problems cause I cant run my Unit Tests under Debugger. I'm forced to change my "ObjectUnderTest" implementation 
to return generic `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T>`, which is fine for the real project, but still is only a workaround.

### The Question is:

Does anybody know the reason for this error? It's definitely related to Portable Class Library magic.

Comment: Have you tried running PEVerify on both assemblies? But this certainly does look like a bug in the compiler or runtime.

Comment: Just did, for both libs. All verified. But thanks for a useful advice, I didn't know about this utility.

Comment: In that case, you should report it to [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 with IntelliTrace enabled? This looks like a bug which should be fixed in the latest [CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36833) of Visual Studio 2012, Update 2 and in future releases.

You can confirm this is the problem (and work around it until you get the fix) by going to Tools/Options/IntelliTrace and turning off 'Enable IntelliTrace'.